# how to install RPM tool without using YUM command

Tags: installation, centos, rpm, yum

I have screwed up with my rpm and yum packages.

Now i don't have both the packages yum as well as RPM

## yum remove rpm.

The above command deleted both yum as well as they have dependency.
Now i cannot proceed with any of the package installation.

It would be great is someone provides me .how to manually install one of this package so that i can install other one.

Comment: I believe this type of questions would better be asked on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

Recovering from this is relatively complicated, since OP would have to successfully replace the `rpm` package as well as any other dependencies removed.

Still, here are the steps I would do if I had to recover a machine like that:

- if I had a comparable machine, I would make a tar file from the list of files obtained using `rpm -ql rpm`, and
- copy that to the target machine to get a workable `rpm` program for *reinstalling* rpm from a package file.

Otherwise

- find (on the network or install-media) the binary package and `rpm`.
- determine the "other" needed packages (from the descriptions on the download page, or on a working machine using `rpm -qpR`*package* for each package)
- on the target machine, extract the files, e.g., using the `unrpm` script (essentially cpio...)

Once I had a workable `rpm` program, I would use that for reinstalling `yum` (and its dependent packages).